# Can we create a control like Account name in the convert lead page?

Tags: apex, visualforce

Can we create a control like account name in the lead conversion page in a VF page? Its like a picklist with lookup.

How does salesforce determine if there is already an account is already present? Is it just by checking the account name? or checks if there is a contact with the same name and email and then verifies the account from the contact too ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create it, but you'd have to do the heavy lifting yourself - there's no apex:inputfield or equivalent that provides this capability.

I've never seen any detail on how the matching takes place - your guesses sound plausible, but I haven't researched it to find out.  Generally, I've produced custom lead conversion because the customer has hard rules around matching and wants to enforce those (or there are a variety of additional objects to be created as part of the conversion).

Comment: Here the need to have a custom VF page is to have an option of creating a event instead of an task